# How can SQL Server assist in the timing of record insertion that violate FK constraints?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a highly relational SQL Server database -- lots of PK/FK relationships.

A custom Windows service keeps this database populated. The Service receives data from other sources, then makes INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements against this database to keep the data up-to-date.

Problem: *I cannot perfectly control the order of the data that comes into this Service*. Sometimes, this comes into conflict with FKs.  Record B comes streaming into the Service, but it's dependent on Record A which will come in milliseconds later.

I cannot remove the FKs from the database. What are my options?

I'm considering building a "holding pen" system into the Service which will sit on failed records then resolve them when their "parent" records finally arrive and are inserted.

However, before I do that, I wanted to see if SQL Server has some method of resolution here?  Is there some feature of SQL that I might be ignorant of that might help in this situation?

Comment: Can you not use transactions and rollback the transaction if the fk is not available otherwise COMMIT ?

Comment: The problem is that transactions need to be time-bound, meaning you need to have a period of time where you add things to the transaction, and then you execute it.  I don't have any time-bounding. Data dribbles into this Service at random. Every bit of data might be the last one ever, for all the Service knows.  It's not "batch/transaction aware."  It's not like a record comes in the the Service can say, "A transaction in starting," and then later say, "The transaction has ended."

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of having FKs on your tables if you're going to be entering data into tables in seemingly random order and potentially violate data integrity? Seems to me you have two solutions. One would be to disable the FKs. Maybe you're able to do that rather than actually deleting them, which you said you cannot do. But the FKs are there to maintain data intrigity (and data modeling). You lose that of course.

The second option would be what you suggested. Store the rows into some temporary storage, and then you can better control entering the master rows before the child rows. However, if you need data in the DB in near real time, this could be a problem.

Actually I have a similar situation with a database I'm responsible for. My FKs are more for modeling purposes as opposed to data integrity, and data can come in, in very random order. So I have my FKs disabled. The FKs still server a purpose, but not for data integrity checks.

Comment: In this case, the FKs only exist for Entity Framework.  This database is not the single source for the data -- it's basically a reporting engine for data that "lives" somewhere else.  So, I'd love to be able to turn the FKs off, but EF requires them.

Comment: @Deane - You can disable FKs and still have them available for EF. EF just requires them to exist, not be enabled.

Comment: That's fantastic information to know, thank you. I'll have to talk with the owner of that process and see if he's willing to go that route.